# How should i apply a style to multiple class libraries?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have multiple class libraries which each contain their own custom user controls. I would like to have a separate common library which contains all of the resource dictionaries used in my project so that i could change say the background color of all the controls used in my project from one location.

What is the best way that i could style all of these controls from a central location?

Answer (score 1):

What I do is have the resource dictionary files in one particular project, then anywhere I need to reference them I merge them in using the "pack" URI syntax. So in a user control, for example:-

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/SomeApplication.Common.UI;component/Themes/Metro/colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/SomeApplication.Common.UI;component/Themes/Metro/buttonstyles.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/SomeApplication.Common.UI;component/Themes/Metro/fonts.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <!-- Any "local" user control styles go here -->
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

The "pack" syntax takes this form:-

> pack://application:,,,/[assembly name];component/[resource path & filename]"

In the above example, "SomeApplication.Common.UI" is the name of my project/assembly where the resource files can be found; the files reside in a project subfolder called "\Themes\Metro". The project with your user controls will obviously need to reference the project/assembly containing the resources!

Also, you don't actually need to merge in the individual resource files for things to work. The application will still compile and run, it's just that you'll get squiggles under style names in the XAML editor, as Visual Studio (or is it Resharper?!) won't be able to resolve them at design time.